# How to navigate to java class declarations from non java extensions such as .conf files?

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8

I have a Java project with a bunch of .conf files. In the conf files, I have class names like this

```
xxx.job_config {
  job_class=com.yyy.class_name
}
```

In Java code which has .java or .class extensions, I am able to click a class name (or other symbols) and navigate to or look at the corresponding declarations. Is there a way to navigate to class declarations from .conf or other non java source files?

In the above example, I want to be able to CTRL + Mouse-Click `class_name` and navigate to that class.

Comment: A special support would be needed from the plug-in responsible for this file type so that it can resolve Java references and provide the navigation feature. It's not possible without plug-in modification.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder. I added the HOCON plugin and it allowed code navigation.